# how to do i trigger a static method in a page that is called by jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery

My problem is that i have a dropdown box that i load the content based on  my selection.However in one of these pages that i get the content i have an static method  that i need to call before showing the content.all the method does is to check if the that value was set in the session. If it was populate the field. Looks like the method does not fire if i load the content using jquery ajax.
Here is the html i am loading based on my selection:

```
    <table>
<tr>
<td><label class="required">Enter Current Number:</label></td><td><input type="text" size=13 id="current_number"  name="current_number" value="<?php echo Util::getSessionValuebySessionName("phonePorting", "current_number"); ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><strong>Please Enter the Address associated to your current phone number</strong>
NOTE: You may only keep your current phone number if the address of your current phone number is in the same state as the address where you are signing up for CenturyLink service. </td></tr>
<tr>
<td width=20%><label class="required">Address Line 1:</label></td><td><input type="text" size=25  id="address_line1"  name="address_line1" value="<?php echo Util::getSessionValuebySessionName("phonePorting", "address_line1"); ?>" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Address Line 2:</td><td><input type="text" size=25  id="address_line2"  name="address_line2" value="<?php echo Util::getSessionValuebySessionName("phonePorting", "address_line2"); ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label class="required">Apartment:</label></td><td><input type="text" size=5  id="Apartment"  name="Apartment"   value="<?php echo Util::getSessionValuebySessionName("phonePorting", "Apartment"); ?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label class="required">City:</label></td><td><input type="text" size=15  id="City"  name="City" value="<?php echo Util::getSessionValuebySessionName("phonePorting", "City"); ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label class="required">State:</label></td><td><select  id="State"  name="State"   >
<option value="">Select a State</option>
<?php foreach (Util::getStatesCodes() as  $key => $value) {?>
<option value="<?php echo $key; ?>" <?php Util::getSessionValuebySessionName("phonePorting", "City")==$key)echo "selected";?>><?php echo $key; ?></option>  
<?php }?>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label class="required">ZipCode:</label></td><td><input type="text" size=15  id="Zipcode"  name="Zipcode"  value="<?php echo Util::getSessionValuebySessionName("phonePorting", "Zipcode"); ?>" ></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is the static method:

```
    public static function getSessionValuebySessionName($ssessionName, $keyName){

    if(!empty($_SESSION[$ssessionName][session_id()][0][$keyName]))
    {
        return $_SESSION[$ssessionName][session_id()][0][$keyName];
    }
```

So pretty much what i want to do is to load the sessions values(in the text fields) if they are not empty  in the html content when i make the selction  in my dropdown. Hope it makes sense.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

problem resolved. I forgot to start the session  in the constructor.....